# Google Analytics - get 10 most popular pages below certain page?

Tags: google-analytics-api

In a subsection of a website, i want do display a "Top 10 most popular", based on the pages below. For example all pages below `www.mydomain.com/products/`.

Can i do this with GA API in Javascript only, or do i need to get some serverside code involved? (.NET)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either reporting JavaScript API 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/libraries
or Embed API
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/

Use ga:pageviews as metrics and use a filter to filter your ga:pagePath